# Retrieving user information from Twitter using Azure Mobile Services

Tags: .net, azure-mobile-services

I've created a Windows mobile app that allows a user to sign in to Twitter using Azure Mobile Services. I'm trying to use a .NET back-end to retrieve information about the user currently signed into Twitter. I have successfully accomplished this when a user signs into Facebook by passing the access token into Facebook's graph API via the following code:

```
var accessToken = fb.AccessToken;
result.Add("facebook", await GetProviderInfo("https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=" + accessToken));
```

However, when attempting the same with Twitter:

```
var accessToken = tw.AccessToken;
result.Add("twitter", await GetProviderInfo("https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token?=" + accessToken));
```

The service throws an error and doesn't return any user information.

I've tried searching for solutions or code examples of retrieving user information from Twitter, but the only resource I can find is for retrieving information from Facebook and Microsoft from the following link: http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/10/02/custom-login-scopes-single-sign-on-new-asp-net-web-api-updates-to-the-azure-mobile-services-net-backend/

Comment: Did you find a solution for this in the end?